# Is there a way to start a plot already zoomed on a specific area using plotly?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, zooming, plotly-python

I have a scatter plot made with plotly (specifically offline plotly with the Python API on a Jupyter Notebook) and as you know, plotly makes it easy for the user to zoom and frame specific areas, but I'd like the plot to start already focussed on a specific area of my choosing.

I can't find anything relevant in the documentation (maybe because I don't know where to look or what terms to look up). Is there a way to do this, and if so, how? And how does the setting differ when using subplots rather than a Figure object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you specify your `Layout`, under the `xaxis` and `yaxis` parameters, you can specify a `range`, e.g.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# ...    

layout = go.Layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        range=[0, 100]
    ),
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[100, 200]
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
```

Documentation for this can be found for the `xaxis` [here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-range) and `yaxis` [here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-range).

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression this would "cut" all results outside the range but this is apparently not the case.

Comment: From my testing with plotly express this doesn't work

Answer (score 15):

If your axis includes dates, then make sure you specify the type as date before setting the range. Otherwise, you'll receive unexpected results.

```
start_date = "2019-09-26"
end_date = "2019-10-18"

fig.update_xaxes(type="date", range=[start_date, end_date])
```

If the `fig` consists of subplots with shared x axes (or y axes), you can set the above range to the row and column corresponding to the last shared plot.

The following is for a single-column subplot with each a graph plot in each row, totalling 7 rows.

```
last_row = 7
last_col = 1

fig.update_xaxes(type="date", range=[start, end], row=last_row, col=last_col)
```

Comment: I've been searching around for hours to solve this problem; for something so primitive, it was not easy to find. Oddly, I couldn't find sufficient detail in the official plotly page for [xaxis](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter-xaxis). But a much better documentation for [xaxis paramenters](https://kite.com/python/docs/plotly.graph_objs.Layout.xaxis) in Kite helped me arrive to the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, range within layout works. I was unable to use

```
...
type = "date",
xaxis = dict[date1, date2]
```

but converting the (POSIXct) dates to numeric worked for me.

(not enough rep to comment, but I felt it was worth adding that conversion works if date ranges don't).

Answer (score 0):

Use `aspectratio=go.layout.scene.Aspectratio(x=2, y=2, z=2)` to zoom the plot by 2x.

For example:

```
layout = go.Layout(
  autosize=False, width=1200, height=800,
  title = '3D Spherical Topography Map',
  titlefont = dict(family='Courier New', color=titlecolor),
  showlegend = False,
  scene = dict(
    xaxis = noaxis,
    yaxis = noaxis,
    zaxis = noaxis,
    aspectmode='manual',
    aspectratio=go.layout.scene.Aspectratio(
      x=2, y=2, z=2)),
  paper_bgcolor = bgcolor,
  plot_bgcolor = bgcolor)
```